# Get data from 2 table to display in 1 table using codeigniter and oracle

Tags: oracle, codeigniter

I want to display a table in my website, and get data from 2 table is TB_KELUHAN and TB_UNIT. Here is the code for controller

```
public function index()
{
    $data['TB_KELUHAN']=$this->computer_model->get_all_computers();
    $this->load->view('header');
    $this->load->view('computer_view',$data);
    $this->load->view('footer');
}
```

Model :

```
var $table = 'TB_KELUHAN';   

public function get_all_computers()
{
    $this->db->from('TB_KELUHAN');
    $query=$this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

And View:

```
<?php foreach($TB_KELUHAN as $computer){?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $computer->IDKELUHAN; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $computer->NAMA; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $computer->IDUNIT; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $computer->TGL_KELUHAN; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $computer->ID_JENISKELUHAN; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $computer->KELUHAN; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $computer->STATUS; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $computer->IDPEGAWAI; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $computer->TGL_SELESAI; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php }?>
```

With `TB_UNIT` like below

```
(   "IDUNIT" NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"UNIT" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
 CONSTRAINT "TB_UNIT_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("IDUNIT")
```

and `TB_KELUHAN` :

```
(   "IDKELUHAN" NUMBER(20,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"NAMA" VARCHAR2(10 BYTE), 
"IDUNIT" NUMBER(10,0), 
"TGL_KELUHAN" DATE DEFAULT sysdate, 
"KELUHAN" VARCHAR2(200 BYTE), 
"STATUS" VARCHAR2(10 BYTE), 
"IDPEGAWAI" NUMBER(10,0), 
"TGL_SELESAI" DATE DEFAULT sysdate, 
"ID_JENISKELUHAN" NUMBER(5,0), 
 CONSTRAINT "TB_KELUHAN_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("IDKELUHAN")
```

I want to display a table in my website using 2 table above that `IDUNIT` field contain `UNIT` from `TB_UNIT`. But, the other field from `TB_KELUHAN`.

I've read using JOIN, how that code? Thanks.

Comment: please refer this documentation for join table
https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html?highlight=join#CI_DB_query_builder::join

Comment: I'm still confused how apply that code to display in view file?

Comment: show me output of array using `print_r($data['TB_KELUHAN']);` in your controller

Answer (score 0):

To join between table `TB_UNIT` and `TB_KELUHAN` just do like below:

```
public function get_all_computers()
{
    $query = $this->db->from('TB_UNIT u')
    ->join('TB_KELUHAN k','k.IDUNIT = u.IDUNIT','left')
    ->get();

    if($query)
    {
      $result = $query->result();
      return $result;
    }

}
```

You may refer to this link for further information:
https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm still confused, how about file view to display UNIT field?